# User Id Mismatch

Tags: square-connect

Any reason for this specific error? As well what exactly should the user ID be.

2015-01-09 15:17:29.187 com.rosettmobile.clienteling[8909:2575054] Request UR2 Encoded :: square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data=%7B%22state%22:%22Useful%20information%22,%22callback_url%22:%22rosettaclienteling:%5C/%5C/my%5C/callback%5C/path%22,%22merchant_id%22:%22brandyn.brosemer@rosetta.com%22,%22amount_money%22:%7B%22amount%22:100,%22currency_code%22:%22USD%22%7D,%22options%22:%7B%22clear_default_fees%22:true,%22supported_tender_types%22:%5B%22CREDIT_CARD%22%5D%7D,%22client_id%22:%22I4C8ySW_Z5UUoP7GYAilpg%22,%22sdk_version%22:%221%22%7D

(lldb) po parameters
{
    data = "{\"status\":\"error\",\"error_code\":\"user_id_mismatch\",\"state\":\"Useful information\"}";
}

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `merchant_id` parameter in the above request is incorrect (a merchant’s ID is different from their email address). You can get a merchant’s `merchant_id` by sending a GET request to the [Retrieve Merchant](http://docs.connect.squareup.com/#get-merchantid) endpoint (`https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me`). The `id` field of the returned JSON object is the merchant's `merchant_id`.